# questions on 0xff

Tags: c++

I am working on a C++ code. Not very sure what the code below is trying to do. Would like someone's help on it.

```
int pval = t_gamma[depth[i]];
        int lb = pval & 0xff;
        switch (pval>>8) {
            case 0:
                depth_mid[3*i+0] = 255;
                depth_mid[3*i+1] = 255-lb;
                depth_mid[3*i+2] = 255-lb;
                break;
            case 1:
                depth_mid[3*i+0] = 255;
                depth_mid[3*i+1] = lb;
                depth_mid[3*i+2] = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                depth_mid[3*i+0] = 255-lb;
                depth_mid[3*i+1] = 255;
                depth_mid[3*i+2] = 0;
                break;
            case 3:
                depth_mid[3*i+0] = 0;
                depth_mid[3*i+1] = 255;
                depth_mid[3*i+2] = lb;
                break;
            case 4:
                depth_mid[3*i+0] = 0;
                depth_mid[3*i+1] = 255-lb;
                depth_mid[3*i+2] = 255;
                break;
            case 5:
                depth_mid[3*i+0] = 0;
                depth_mid[3*i+1] = 0;
                depth_mid[3*i+2] = 255-lb;
                break;
            default:
                depth_mid[3*i+0] = 0;
                depth_mid[3*i+1] = 0;
                depth_mid[3*i+2] = 0;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: You wrote this or found this? What is it part of? What is the overall code trying to do? Or are you just wondering what this 0xff is?

Comment: You are working on *a* c++ code? Just one? Doesn't make any sense

Comment: lb can also mean low byte right?

Comment: i found this code, would like to understand it...

Comment: strange stuff, right shift 8 bits, but only interested in the rightmost 3 bits after that operation.  just odd.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`0xff` means "the hexadecimal number `ff`" - in other words, the integer `255`, which has the binary representation `00000000000000000000000011111111` (when using 32-bit integers). The `&` operator performs a bitwise AND operation. `a & b` will give you an integer with a bit pattern that has a `0` in all positions where `b` has a `0`, while in all positions where `b` has a `1`, the corresponding bit value from `a` is used (this also goes the other way around). For example, the bitwise AND of `10110111` and `00001101` is `00000101`.

In this case, `pval & 0xff` will give you the rightmost 8 bits from `pval`.

As for what the code does, I believe it tries to transform color values from a special format to standard RGB: the color values seem to contain eleven bits, where three of them indicate a color range (for example, `000` seems to indicate the range "white to blue", while `001` indicates "red to yellow"), and the rightmost eight bits indicate a color in this range.

Answer (score 1):

```
int lb = pval & 0xff;
```

This operation performs a bitwise AND operation on **pval** with **0xff**.

Because 0xff is represented as 1's in the lower 8 bits of the integer, it effectively masks **pval** so it leaves only the value in the last 8 bits.

So, in other words it just ignores all the rest of the integer value, and does a simple modulo 256 calculation. But usually it's just for retrieving the last bits.

Comment: i understand the part that the last 8 bits is given to lb. but why is it a simple modulo 256 calculation? not very sure abt it..

Comment: lets look at a 4 bit example: 1111 = 15 now add 1 to that, and you get 10000 which is 16 or 0 mod 16. next bit is 110000 which 32+16 (you can see that any other bit added is just a multiple of 16) ... same thing goes to 256.. next bit is 512(2*256) next is 1024(4*256) etc..

Answer (score 1):

pval is an int, but the lowest 8 bits have a special meaning, and the rest of the bits have another

```
           3               1
           1               6        8        0
          +--------+--------+--------+--------+
pval =    |aaaaaaaa|aaaaaaaa|aaaaaaaa|bbbbbbbb|
          +--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

The code 'int lb = pval & 0xff' returns just the value of the 'b' bits.

pval >> 8 returns the value of the 'a' bits.

As to what the code is doing, it seems to me that it's converting some data to a colour map so it can be displayed. There's not enough information to be really sure though.